# How to Use StructureMap From A Static Class in Web API 2?

Tags: c#, static, asp.net-web-api2, structuremap, fody

I have a WebApi Solution and I am using [StructureMap.WebApi2](https://github.com/webadvanced/Structuremap.WebAPI2) Nuget Package for Dependency Injection.

I want to use [Fody Tracer](https://github.com/csnemes/tracer) to weave in trace methods.  I am [implementing my own custom log adapter](https://github.com/csnemes/tracer/wiki/Create-your-own-logging-adapter) which requires me to return an instance of my logger from a static class/method.

What is the proper way for me to use Structure Map to get an instance of my logger from a static class/method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditionally you would use StructureMap's `ObjectFactory.GetInstance<T>` to resolve your static method's dependencies. However, this has since been deprecated as it's typically frowned on because using it tightly couples your code to the IoC container (see [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) on the Service Locator anti-pattern).

The next best approach is to create your own static equivalent of the ObjectFactory that returns an IContainer instance, similar to this:

```
public static class ObjectFactory  
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Container> _containerBuilder = new Lazy<Container>(defaultContainer, LazyThreadSafetyMode.ExecutionAndPublication);

    public static IContainer Container
    {
        get { return _containerBuilder.Value; }
    }

    private static Container defaultContainer()
    {
            return new Container(x => { 
                x.AddRegistry(new YourRegistry()) };
            });
    }
}
```

See [this](http://dennisrongo.com/resolving-the-structuremap-objectfactory-is-obsolete-warning-message/) post for a more in-depth implementation.

Comment: I'm currently working on implementing this solution.  Once I verify it works, I will accept the answer.  Thanks!